# SQL - display selective output that is not sequenced last in a multiple occurrence

Tags: sql, multiple-conditions

I have a table like below

```
OP    OP_var    SPS    SPS_sq
1010    01    KEB_x    01
1010    01    KEK_x    02
1010    02    KEH_c    01
1010    02    KEK_y    02
1010    02    KEB_d    03
1020    01    KEK_f    01
1020    01    KEE_g    02
```

The OP column has variance (OP_var) and within it is a group of SPS. SPS_sq is the sequencing of these SPS lines within the `OP+OP_var`.

I would like to display KEK% where the KEK%'s SPS_sq is not last (meaning, the KEK% is either first or anywhere in the middle of the sequence number of the OP and OP_var as long as it is not last.

The output should look like this :

```
OP     OP_var     SPS     SPS_sq
1010     02       KEK_y    02
1020     01       KEK_f    01
```

ignore all `KEK%` that is SPS_sq last within the `OP+OP_var`.

Comment: Why is there no output for `1010 01` ?

Comment: Hi Andomar, because, the KEK in 1010 01 is the last KEK (by referring to the SPS_sq column, which is the sequence column for the SPS within the OP+OP_var).  I only need KEK that is not last. Thank u.

Comment: Ah, ok.  What database are you using (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, ...)  And when you edit your question, be sure to use [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), not HTML.

Comment: if you have let's say 3 KEK% sps by op, op_var, and one is the last, you want the 2 others, or just one ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus - I want all the ones that are not last :)

Comment: @Andomar - PL/SQL Developer

Answer (score 0):

If you want all kek where kek is not at the max sps_sq for (op, op_var)

```
select * from Table1 t
where t.sps like 'KEK%' 
and not exists
(select null from Table1 t1
inner join (select MAX(t2.sps_sq) as maxsps_sq, t2.op, t2.op_var 
            from Table1 t2
            GROUP BY t2.op, t2.op_var) as getmax
on t1.op = getmax.op and t1.op_var = getmax.op_var 
 and t1.sps_sq = getmax.maxsps_sq
where t1.op = t.op and t1.op_var = t.op_var and t1.sps = t.sps and t.sps_sq = t1.sps_sq
);
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/176f9/1)

Caution :
As Andomar's noticed, this will take all the kek% for an [op, op_var] which don't have the last sps_sq number.

Comment: Could return multiple rows per `(op, op_var)`, see [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05387/1/0)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus - I have tried your query, some entries are missing..i am still trying to find out whether some of my additional filtration is missing or it's the system...will update..

Comment: @user2408833 hmmm, I may guess where the error comes from. Will also update

Comment: @user2408833 edited Fiddle again with some comments, hope it makes things clearer...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for a random row per `(op, op_var)` combination.  The random row has to have an SPS like `'KEK%'`, and it cannot have the same SPS as the last row.  (That implies it cannot be the last row itself.)

This example uses window functions, which are available in SQL Server, Oracle, PostGRES.  It uses a SQL Server specific way (`newid()`) to create a random order.

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by yt1.OP, yt1.OP_var
                    order by newid()) as rn2 -- Random order
        ,       yt1.*
        from    dbo.YourTable yt1
        join    (
                select  row_number() over (
                            partition by OP, OP_var
                            order by SPS_sq desc) as rn
                ,       *
                from    YourTable
                ) as last_row
        on      yt1.OP = last_row.OP
                and yt1.OP_var = last_row.OP_var
                and last_row.rn = 1 -- Highest SPS_sq
        where   yt1.SPS <> last_row.SPS
                and yt1.SPS like 'KEK%'
        ) SubQueryALias
where   rn2 = 1 -- Random KEK row that doesn't share SPS with last row
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cf9e8/1)

Comment: Andomar, there is a possibility that there is a repetition of SPS in a OP+OP_var. Sorry i should have mentioned this earlier. SPS is a process. it can be repeated within a group.